# Java Change Prompt Order

Tags: java

I am currently working on a java program that has to do with taking classes and the amount of credits for each class. I have everything set up how I need it, except the order.

I would like it to ask for a class, then how many credits that class is, then ask for the next class, and those credits, and so on. Right now, it will ask for all of the classes, then all of the credits. Here's the code I have:

```html
//Jake Petersen
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test1{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many courses are you going to list?");
    int courses = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    String courseArray[] = new String[courses];
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++){
      System.out.println("Please enter a course:");
      courseArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }
    int creditArray[] = new int[courses];
    for (int i = 0; i < creditArray.length;) {
      System.out.println("Please enter how many credits "+ courseArray[i] + " is:");
      int input = scan.nextInt();
      if (input >= 1 && input <= 4) {
        creditArray[i++] = input; 
      }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : creditArray){
      sum += i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(courseArray[i] + " is a " + creditArray[i] + " credit class. \n");
    }
    print(sum);
  }
  public static void print(int sum){
    if(sum >= 12 && sum <= 18){
      System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which makes you a full time student.");
    }else if(sum < 12){
      System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which makes you not a full time student.");
    }else{
      System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which means you are overloaded"); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all the prompts in a single for loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many courses are you going to list?");
        int courses = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        String courseArray[] = new String[courses];
        int creditArray[] = new int[courses];
        for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Please enter a course:");
            courseArray[i] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter how many credits "+ courseArray[i] + " is:");
            String credits = scan.nextLine();
            int input = Integer.parseInt(credits);
            if (input >= 1 && input <= 4) {
                creditArray[i] = input;
            }
            else {
                creditArray[i] = 0;
            }
        }    int sum = 0;
        for (int i : creditArray){
            sum += i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(courseArray[i] + " is a " + creditArray[i] + " credit class. \n");
        }
        print(sum);
    }
    public static void print(int sum){
        if(sum >= 12 && sum <= 18){
            System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which makes you a full time student.");
        }else if(sum < 12){
            System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which makes you not a full time student.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You are taking " + sum + " total credits, which means you are overloaded");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes that the 2 arrays have the same size.  Perhaps you want to prompt for a class count first, to know how large to make the arrays, or grow them dynamically.

Comment: I tried this and it seems that after it records the first credit amount, it will ask for the second course but not allow the user to input the name of the course, instead it prints "Please enter a course" then immediately prints "Please enter how many credits  is"

Comment: use System.out.print instead of println, since the scanner may be reading the newline.  Also, you generally want to leave the cursor on the same line as the prompt.

Comment: Even after changing println to print, it still does not do the trick. I also discovered that changing this causes the valid integer checker to not work, you can input whatever number you would like if I put this code in there.

Comment: Hi Jake.  I figured out what was going on.  I saw that it worked first time through loop, but showed this behavior on second.  Problem was that scan.nextInt() read the int for number of credits, but leaves the newline in the input scream, so when we go back to top to read scan.nextLine(), it finds the newline, so that scan.nextLine() returns immediately.  I updated my answer with code that I ran that works.  Try it.

Comment: As for user typing in anything for credit count, you're going to have to handle it by wrapping the ParseInt in a try/catch, and do the credit reading in a loop, breaking when a valid number is entered.